# How to override .toString method for ordered-set

Tags: string, clojure, println

I'm using ordered-set for some stuff in Clojure 1.3.0.  My `project.clj` includes `[ordered "1.1.0"]`.

When I call `(str (ordered-set 1 2 3))` I get `"ordered.set.OrderedSet@6"` but when I call a normal clojure hash-set `(str (hash-set 1 2 3))` I get the correct `"#{1 2 3}"` as a result.

The `str` method calls `.toString` somewhere, so how do I override the `.toString` method for `ordered-set` so I can get a proper string out of it?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are two answers to this question. One is, the lazy maintainer of `ordered` (me) should get his act together and implement `toString`. The other is, you probably shouldn't be using `str` on anything where you care about readability - `pr-str` is a much more reliable data-presentation function. For example, `(str {:a 'a})` and `(str {:a "a"})` both result in `"{:a a}"`. With `pr-str` the type information remains.

Comment: @Sonicsmooth Version 1.2.0 is released and contains `.toString` implementations, though I still caution you against using them.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still not clear about the differences between str and pr-str, except pr-str seems to provide a nice-to-read output, so I'll use that for now until I understand better what's going on.